# cannot crawl data from farfetch using scrapy

Tags: html, css, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to get price information from `farfetch.com` using scrapy, but I only get an empty list.
This is a block of html from farfetch:

```
<div class="bc2ed6" data-tstid="priceInfo-priceInfo" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <span>
    <strong data-tstid="priceInfo-original" class="d9c839 _62e534">$1,190</strong>
    <small class="_840e33 eda00d" data-tstid="dutiesInformation" dir="LTR">(<!-- -->Import duties included<!-- -->)</small>
  </span>
  <meta itemprop="price" content="1190"><meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
  <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition">
  <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
</div>
```

and I test my code in the scrapy shell, it returns empty until some root tag:

```
>> response.css('main').css('section').css('div#slice-pdp').css('div.bc2ed6')
[]
>> response.css('main').css('section').css('div#slice-pdp')
[]
>> response.css('main').css('section').css('div#globalPos')
[<Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::div[@id = 'globalPos']" data=u'<div id="globalPos" class="info-banners-'>]
>> response.css('main').css('section')
[<Selector xpath=u'descendant-or-self::section' data=u'<section><!-- error message --><div id="'>]
```

Does anyone know why it is and how can I solve it?

Ps: there is `<script>..<script>` between `<div id="globalPos"...>` and `<div id="slice-pdp"...>`, is this the reason?

Answer (score 0):

When using your example in scrapy shell

```
scrapy shell file:///home/user/scrapy/so/so_51375033_part.html
```

I get the price information:

```
In [11]: response.css('div.bc2ed6').css('meta::attr(content)').extract()
Out[11]: ['1190', 'USD']
```

So when you are able to adress bc2ed6 getting the price information out of the inner html part is quite easy.